# How to check first the user is login or not in firebase using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

**my code:**

```
  void initState() {
        super.initState();
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen())));
      }
```

Here it is my initState it shows a login screen for a second and i dont want it..
Solutions are welcome.

Comment: I don't how people upvote these types of _I don't want_ questions, and your code and title didn't relate and even show some research

Comment: @PeterHaddad what i do if i dont want the splash screen

Comment: check my answer @DarshanKhadse

Comment: @DarshanKhadse If my answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for the applications i build, i maintain a **boolean variable called "auth"** in the user object and change that to true once the user signs in.

And ideally there is a **"Splash Screen"** with this code.

```
if(user.auth)
{
  //User Authenticated
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen())));

}else{

  //User not Authenticated
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen())));
}
```

After authenticating, do not forget to store the user object or the auth variable in local storage / [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) so that the data is not lost once the user exits the app.

**Code for saving user object :**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

prefs.setString("current_user",json.encode(user.toJson()));
```

**User class :**

```
class User{
  final String username;
  final String email;

  //is user signed in?
  bool isAuth;


  User({this.username, this.email,this.isAuth});

  User.fromData(Map<String,dynamic> data)
  : username  = data['Username'],
    email     = data['email'],
    isAuth    = data['isAuth'] ?? false,


  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "Username" : username,
      "email"    : email,
      "isAuth"   : isAuth ?? false,
    };
  }
```

Let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase authentication to check if the user is logged in or not. First create a splash screen:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Meet Up',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
        home: IntroScreen(),);

  }
}
```

In the `IntroScreen()` StatefulWidget you can check if user is logged in or not and navigate to the specific page:

```
class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget{


  @override
  _IntroScreenState createState() => _IntroScreenState();
}

class _IntroScreenState extends State<IntroScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((res) {
      print(res);
      if (res != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
        );
      }
      else
      {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
        seconds: 5,
        title: new Text('Welcome To Meet up!',
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20.0
          ),),
        image: Image.asset('assets/images/dart.png',fit:BoxFit.scaleDown),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 100.0,
        onClick: ()=>print("flutter"),
        loaderColor: Colors.red
    );
  }
}
```

https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen

Comment: it stucked on Login Page...it repeatedly showing the login page